# POSTing data to the server, behind the scenes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm building a website which has a page that users can add content to, and they can rearrange the divs to whichever position and size they want.  I'd like to have a save button which saves the current position of each div; however, I don't want the page to refresh each time (I'm also going to have an auto-save, which will have to save the information in the background).

I can't figure out how to post the data to the server though, without causing the page to reload.  I figure I need some kind of AJAX request, but can't find anything that tells me how to do that (all the AJAX examples I can find seem to be about reading data from the server).  I think I'm just starting to go round in circles now, but I can't get my head around this at all - I know it's probably not a hard thing to do, but I keep getting confused by the different examples.

So, first of all, is this the best way to do it?  And, if so, can someone point me to a straightforward example of posting data via AJAX?  I'm already using jQuery, so can use that for the Ajax as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Super simple AJAX with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/save-the-stuff-url',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        // information about your divs, etc.
        'foo' : 'bar'
    },
    success: function(response) {
        // if the AJAX call completes successfully, this function will get called.
        alert('POST successful!');
    }
});
```

Give it a shot!

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this for AJAX:

```
$.post("example.php", {
        from : "ajax", // put some info in these - they are the params
        time : "2pm",
        data : "save"
    },
    function(data) { // callback function - data always passed to it
        $("#success").html(data); // do something with that data
    }
);
```

And put this somewhere:

```
<span id='success'></span>
```

And then, try this example for example.php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['from']) and $_POST['from'] == 'ajax'){
        echo "<span style='color: green;'>Saved!</span>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<span style='color: red;'>Failure!</span>";
    }
?>
```

And then just modify these to fit your needs, probably changing the file of target. Whatever the script outputs is what is given to the ajax request. This means that if this was my PHP script:

```
<?php echo "Aloha!"; ?>
```

And this was my javascript:

```
$("#output").load("myScript.php");
```

Then `#output` would have "`Aloha!`" in it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the [Jquery site](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for various examples of post.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

and the jQuery docs pages are a great way to learn jQuery.. the page for post is http://docs.jquery.com/Post

you may also want to look at jQuery draggables if you're not using that yet..

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Draggable

you can fire a save tied to your draggable object being let go rather easily with

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
   stop: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```